# Unable to import custom fonts

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fonts, tailwind-css

I just created a nextjs app, and I am running into problem, I am not able to import custom fonts, I tried adding ttg files, and used @fontface, but the fonts are not working. Please help

Here is my globals.css file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
    font-family: 'bornStrong';
    src: url(/public/fonts/BornStrong-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'heywow';
    src: url(/public/fonts/HeyWow-Regular.ttf); 
}

html, body {
    font-family: 'heywow';
}

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: 'heywow';
}

.main {
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 120px 24px 160px 24px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.main:before {
  background: #1c1d25;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.main:after {
  content: "";
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  filter: invert(1);
}

.gradient {
  height: fit-content;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(100px) saturate(150%);
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 0.15;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .main {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

/* Tailwind Styles */

.app {
  @apply relative z-10 flex justify-center items-center flex-col max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-16 px-6;
}

.black_btn {
  @apply rounded-full border border-black bg-black py-1.5 px-5 text-white transition-all hover:bg-white hover:text-black text-center text-sm flex items-center justify-center;
}

.outline_btn {
  @apply rounded-full border border-black bg-transparent py-1.5 px-5 text-black transition-all hover:bg-black hover:text-white text-center text-sm flex items-center justify-center;
}

.head_text {
  @apply mt-5 text-5xl font-extrabold leading-[1.15] text-black sm:text-6xl;
}

.orange_gradient {
  @apply bg-gradient-to-r from-amber-500 via-orange-600 to-yellow-500 bg-clip-text text-transparent;
}

.green_gradient {
  @apply bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-green-500 bg-clip-text text-transparent;
}

.blue_gradient {
  @apply bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-600 to-cyan-600 bg-clip-text text-transparent;
}

.desc {
  @apply mt-5 text-lg text-gray-600 sm:text-xl max-w-2xl;
}

.search_input {
  @apply block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-white py-2.5 pl-5 pr-12 text-sm shadow-lg font-medium focus:border-black focus:outline-none focus:ring-0;
}

.copy_btn {
  @apply w-7 h-7 rounded-full bg-white/10 shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199,199,199,0.2)] backdrop-blur flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer;
}

.glassmorphism {
  @apply rounded-xl border border-gray-200 bg-white/20 shadow-[inset_10px_-50px_94px_0_rgb(199,199,199,0.2)] backdrop-blur p-5;
}

.prompt_layout {
  @apply space-y-6 py-8 sm:columns-2 sm:gap-6 xl:columns-3;
}

/* Feed Component */
.feed {
  @apply mt-16 mx-auto w-full max-w-xl flex justify-center items-center flex-col gap-2;
}

/* Form Component */
.form_textarea {
  @apply w-full flex rounded-lg h-[200px] mt-2 p-3 text-sm text-gray-500 outline-0;
}

.form_input {
  @apply w-full flex rounded-lg mt-2 p-3 text-sm text-gray-500 outline-0;
}

/* Nav Component */
.logo_text {
  @apply max-sm:hidden font-semibold text-lg text-black tracking-wide;
}

.dropdown {
  @apply absolute right-0 top-full mt-3 w-full p-5 rounded-lg bg-white min-w-[210px] flex flex-col gap-2 justify-end items-end;
}

.dropdown_link {
  @apply text-sm text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500 font-medium;
}

/* PromptCard Component */
.prompt_card {
  @apply flex-1 break-inside-avoid rounded-lg border border-gray-300 bg-white/20 bg-clip-padding p-6 pb-4 backdrop-blur-lg backdrop-filter md:w-[360px] w-full h-fit;
}

.flex-center {
  @apply flex justify-center items-center;
}

.flex-start {
  @apply flex justify-start items-start;
}

.flex-end {
  @apply flex justify-end items-center;
}

.flex-between {
  @apply flex justify-between items-center;
```

here is my tailwind.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'primary-orange': '#FF5722',
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Here is my layout.jsx file,

```
import '@styles/globals.css';

const layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>AUHISI</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default layout;
```

here is my page.jsx file

```
import '@styles/globals.css';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

I tried adding tailwind as `className="font-bornStrong"`, but it still didn't work.

I also tried to add that font in tailwind.config.js.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        bornStrong: ['bornStrong'],
        heywow: ['heywow'],
      },
      colors: {
        'primary-orange': '#FF5722',
      }
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is likely due to the incorrect path specified for your custom fonts in the `globals.css` file. you're using the path `/public/fonts/` to reference the font files but this path is not correct in Next.jsn, to fix the issue, you need to update the font file paths in your globals.css file and you can remove the /public/ portion from the font file paths.

in your `tailwind.config.js` file, you have defined the font families, but you haven't enabled them in the fontFamily section

```
  variants: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: ['bornStrong', 'heywow'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I Follow this method, that's works for me. I have insert that font links by using `<Head>` tag.

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/pricedown" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

after that, I modified my tailwindcss.config file

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        PricedownBl : ['Pricedown Bl', 'sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```